# SVR predicts same value for all features

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm creating a basic application to predict the 'Closing' value of a stock for day n+1, given features of stock n using Python and Scikit-learn

A sample row in my dataframe looks like this (2000 rows)

```
       Open     Close    High     Low      Volume     
0      537.40   537.10   541.55   530.47   52877.98
```

Similar to this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SSu00IRRraY, where he uses 'Dates' and 'Open Price'. In this example, Dates are the features and Open price is the target.

Now in my example, I don't have a 'Dates' value in my dataset, but instead want to use Open, High, Low, Volume data as the features because I thought that would make it more accurate

I was defining my features and targets as so

```
features = df.loc[:,df.columns != 'Closing']
targets = df.loc[:,df.columns  == 'Closing']
```

Which would return a  df looking like this
features:

```
       Open      High      Low      Vol from  
29     670.02    685.11    661.09   92227.36
```

targets:

```
       Close
29     674.57
```

However I realised that the data needs to be in a numpy array, so I now get my features and targets like this

```
features = df.loc[:,df.columns != 'Closing'].values
targets = df.loc[:,df.columns  == 'Closing'].values
```

So now my features look like this

```
[6.70020000e+02 6.85110000e+02 6.61090000e+02 9.22273600e+04
  6.23944806e+07]
 [7.78102000e+03 8.10087000e+03 7.67541000e+03 6.86188500e+04
  5.41391322e+08]
```

and my targets look like this

```
[  674.57]
[ 8042.64]
```

I then split up my data using

```
X_training, X_testing, y_training, y_testing = train_test_split(features, targets, test_size=0.8)
```

I tried to follow the Scikit-Learn documentation, which resulted in the following

```
svr_rbf = svm.SVR(kernel='rbf', C=100.0, gamma=0.0004, epsilon= 0.01 )
svr_rbf.fit(X_training, y_training)
predictions = svr_rbf.predict(X_testing)
print(predictions)
```

I assumed that this would predict the Y values given the testing features, which I could then plot against the actual y_testing values to see how similar they are. However, the predictions is printing out the same value for each X_testing feature.

```
[3763.84681818 3763.84681818 3763.84681818 3763.84681818 3763.84681818
```

I've tried changing the value of epsilon, c and gamma but that doesnt seem to change the fact that the predictions always gives the same value

I know that it might not be accurate to predict stock prices, but I must have done something wrong to get the same value when applying the model to various different test data

Comment: (1) You may wish to try tinkering with regularization param, `C`, and see if that will result in the output changing together with input. (2) You may wish to explore different preprocessing schemes to apply to your features prior to SVM.

Answer (score 1):

You should normalize your features before using SVM for a classification task.
SVMs are usually sensible to non-normalized features. Since your 5th feature is like 10,000 times greater than your 4 other features, it literally dominates your other features.

Have a look at this link which explains your issue very clearly:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/57010/is-it-essential-to-do-normalization-for-svm-and-random-forest